# I'm trying to convert my normal email program in laravel into sending email using queue

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

I'm trying to convert my normal email program in laravel into sending email using queue

THIS IS THE CODE IN CONTROLLER (SIMPLE MAIL code) >>

```
public function basic_email(){
    $user = DB::select(DB::raw('select emailid from items where created_at = (select max(`created_at`) from items)'));
    $content = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");

    Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $content, function($message) use ($user){
        $message->from('guptavaishalibdn@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
        $message->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
        foreach($user as $u){
            $message->to($u->emailid);    
        }
    });
    echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

Its Working Properly
I TRIED TO CONVERT IT INTO THE QUEUE>>

```
public function basic_email(){
    $user = DB::select(DB::raw('select emailid from items where created_at = (select max(`created_at`) from items)'));  
    $content = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");
    $this->dispatch(new MailJob($content,$user));
}
```

CODE IN JOB>>

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class MailJob implements ShouldQueue
{ 
    private $content;
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(Content $content, User $user){
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->user= $user;
    }
    public function handle(){   
        Mail::queue(['text'=>'mail'], $content, function($message) use ($user){
        $message->from('guptavaishalibdn@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
        $message->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
        foreach($user as $u){
            $message->to($u->emailid);    
        }
    });
  echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

WEB.PHP is same for both

Route::get('sendbasicemail','MailController@basic_email');

and all set in queue.php/mail.php/.env
such as queue driver: database
and all the mailing credentials
 and I'm getting an error that MailJob class is not found in MailController.php
I tried this

```
use App/Jobs/MailJob;
```

still having the same error
I'm a very begineer in Laravel
AND PLEASE TELL ME ALL THE MISTAKES IN MY CODE

Comment: Update composer and clear cache also then try again..

Comment: still having the same error

Comment: its done by composer update but now I'm having This Error

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\MailJob::__construct() must be an instance of App\Jobs\Content, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctd-officedesk\app\Http\Controllers\MailController.php on line 46

Comment: Now I am positive that the arguments which I am passing when creating a new job in my controller are proper but It seems there is an issue in the way I'm referencing the variables in my handler.

Whats going wrong here?


 public function __construct(Content $content, User $user)

Comment: Try like this:  public function __construct(Request $request) {
   $id = $request->get("id");
}

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\MailJob::__construct() must be an instance of App\Jobs\Request, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctd-officedesk\app\Http\Controllers\MailController.php on line 46

Comment: Add APP/  to the param:  public function __construct(App\User $user)
{
    $this->user=$user;
}

Comment: But we passed those parameters in constructor  which are going to use in the logic in handle()

Comment: check the updated code of MailJob class Now I'm Having THis

         Undefined variable: content

here


        Mail::queue(['text'=>'mail'], $content, function($message) use 
      ($user){

Comment: I think you should debug that in each function data is recieve or not?